# Server-to-server SFTP transfer without using temporary file

Tags: c#, sftp, ssh.net

We are currently using WinSCP to transfer files using SFTP, but we would like to get away from having to save our file locally between two SFTP servers. Is there a way to have my application act as a "middleman" without saving the file locally? For example, a user clicks a button than the application grabs a file from SFTP Server A, then transfers it to SFTP Server B without me having to save the file locally in between. Here is the code I am using, or trying to use:

```
using (SftpClient clientSSA = new SftpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSA.IP"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSA.Username"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSA.Password"]))
{
    using (SftpClient clientTracker = new SftpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tracker.IP"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tracker.Username"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tracker.Password"]))
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            String remotePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\", "Wages", "wage_request.txt");
            String trackerPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\", "Wages", "wage_response_RENCI.txt");

            clientSSA.Connect();
            clientSSA.DownloadFile(remotePath, stream);

            clientTracker.Connect();
            clientTracker.UploadFile(stream, trackerPath);
        }
    }
}
```

If SSH.net is not capable of doing this, what component out there will let me?